# Going live from sandbox in jive

Tags: sandbox, jive

we are in one situation where there is one live website of jive for the current client and its new design and changes along with editing and updating the contents to be done on a sandbox jive website. Our issue is how to go live after we edit and update the design and apply the necessary changes? The live website is currently accepting new discussions, posts from live user. So how can we achieve the transition from sandbox to live website? It will be helpful for us if you can provide us any reference to this issue, which is accessible by us. Regards.

Comment: You want to update the existing live jive instance with the changes and content made on the sandbox jive instance or you want to bring the content from the existing instance to the sandbox and then make this instance the live one?

Comment: If "new design" means that you were using the theme tool, then you can export the theme and then import into the prod instance.  If you are talking about custom tiles, you need to install the add-on in prod, and then make the changes to the landing pages.  There is no deployment mechanism to get from dev to prod... it's just a manual exercise.  If you are concerned about it causing interruptions with the users, then do it off hours.  If you think the risk is high, then you can turn on a maintenance page (the method of doing that differs between hosted and cloud).